# Specs on Apple human interface design like http://material.io/

Tags: ios, human-interface-guideline

I am coming from Android development to iOS development.

Our design was dictated by the awesome detail provided at http://material.io/ - it gives us down to the pixel how many pixels to right/left margin spacing font size etc.

I was trying to create a list item in Android and followed the guide here perfectly - https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html#lists-specs

I cannot find something like this for Apple's human interface design. For example, is there anything with the exact spacings margins and font sizes for list item in iOS design?

I find this - https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/tables/ - but it has no numbers. Just pictures/principals/ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thanks to Ivo Mynttinen, there is a comprehensive design guide based on iOS HCI guide.](https://ivomynttinen.com/blog/ios-design-guidelines)

Just a hint: you can hover over the images in the guide to get a detailed view of the pixel perfect specs.

[image]

I hope this answers your question.

Source: https://ivomynttinen.com/blog/ios-design-guidelines

Comment: Thank you very much Rob E!! This is perfect!! That hover for pixel perfect specs is EXACTLY what I need. It was hidden I didn't realize that on first read through article. Thank you very much!